# lxml findall div and span tags

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

How can I find all div and span tags with order preserved.With BeautifulSoup it is very simple: `soup.findAll(name=['span', 'div'])`, but I switched recently to lxml since it is much faster than BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import lxml.html
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
content = result.read()
page_html = lxml.html.fromstring(content)

elements = page_html.xpath('//*[self::div or self::span]')
```

or

```py
sd_selector = CSSSelector('span,div')
elements = sd_selector(page_html)
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.Which method is faster? I assume that first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
import lxml.html as LH
content = '''\
<tr>
<div>idend</div>
<span>Green<\span>
<tr>
'''
root = LH.fromstring(content)
for tag in root.xpath('//*[self::div or self::span]'):
    print(tag)
```

yields

```
<Element div at 0xb751f23c>
<Element span at 0xb751f11c>
```